# CSS background-image not working with absolute URL

Tags: css

My background image is not working.

CSS:

```
.main {
    color:rgb(5, 1, 0);
    position:absolute;
    border:3px solid lightgreen
    background-image:url("images/some_image.png");
}
```

I've looked it over many times and I can't find what's wrong with this code. The URL is right, the syntax is right... What is wrong with this?

Comment: This is a relative URL not an absolute URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no **semicolon** after the `border` element definition.

Here is the correct definition:

```css
border: 3px solid lightgreen;
background-image: url("images/some_image.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  border:3px solid lightgreen
  background-image:url("images/some_image.png");
```

You seem to have forgotten a semicolon on the line above.

Also, this is a relative, not absolute URL.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  color: rgb(5, 1, 0);
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid lightgreen;
  background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, you're including your `background-image` inside your `border`! Put a semicolon after your border declaration, and your background image should work fine, if `some_image.png` is in the correct directory.

Your css should look like this:

```
.main {
  color:rgb(5, 1, 0);
  position:absolute;
  border:3px solid lightgreen;
  background-image:url("images/some_image.png");

}
```